# Code runs in Python 3, not in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am pretty new to Python and I am just doing a bunch of exercises.
This is one of them, a simple DiceRoller.
It works perfectly fine in ATOM, the issue arises when I try to run it in IDLE. I am unable to figure out why the issue happen. Pretty sure this is a noob question.
The code:

```
import random

dices=[2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100]
Y= ['yes', 'y']
N= ['no', 'n']

def DiceRoller():
    dice_selection=input('Please, choose the dice(d2, d3, etc. - only the number): ')
    try:
        dice = int(dice_selection)
    except ValueError:
        print('You have to select a number, try again')
        DiceRoller()
    if dice not in dices:
        print('You have to select a 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100 faces dice, try again')
        DiceRoller()
    number=input('How many dice(s) do you want to roll? ')
    try:
        numint = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        print('You have to select a number, try again')
        DiceRoller()
    ripet=0
    while ripet < numint:
        ripet += 1
        if dice in dices:
            result=random.randint(1,dice)
            print(result)
    else:
        Continue()

def Continue():
    risposta=input('Do you want to roll again? (Y/N) ')
    rispostal= risposta.lower()
    if rispostal in Y:
        DiceRoller()
    elif rispostal in N:
        return 'Goodbye'
        quit()
    else:
        print('Please, answer Yes or No')
        Continue()

DiceRoller()
```

Errors whit IDLE after the program ask me if I want to roll again (input y or n):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Corso Python\DiceRoller.py", line 44, in <module>
    DiceRoller()
  File "E:\Corso Python\DiceRoller.py", line 30, in DiceRoller
    Continue()
  File "E:\Corso Python\DiceRoller.py", line 33, in Continue
    risposta=input('Do you want to roll again? (Y/N) ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Errors whit IDLE after the program ask me if I want to roll again (input Y or N):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Corso Python\DiceRoller.py", line 44, in <module>
    DiceRoller()
  File "E:\Corso Python\DiceRoller.py", line 30, in DiceRoller
    Continue()
  File "E:\Corso Python\DiceRoller.py", line 34, in Continue
    rispostal= risposta.lower()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: I bet that IDLE runs python2.7 and that's why `input` makes an error... Use `raw_input` in python2.7 and `input` in python3

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input 
In python2 string returned from `input()` is immediately evaluated which causes code to behave like `risposta=y` where `y` is not defined yet in first case, and `risposta=Y`  where `Y` is an array in second.

Comment: It works for me in IDLE with Python 3.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in the atom editor, you use `python3` and your IDLE uses `python2`. In Python 2, the function for reading user's input was called `raw_input()`; [it was renamed to `input()` in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) (section starting with `PEP 3111: raw_input() was renamed to input()`).

You can either ensure you are using `python3` by default or make the code `python2`-compatible: add a code block

```
import sys
compatible_input = raw_input if sys.version_info < (3, 0) else input
```

and replace all usages of `... = input(...)` in your code with `... = compatible_input(...)`.

Comment: To get the code to work with an IDLE using python2, I added `input=raw_input` at the top. Not the ideal solution, but it proves the case.